# Cannot autowire argument $of "App\Controller\HomeController": it references class "Symfony\Component\Form\SubmitButton" but no such service exists

Tags: php, symfony, autowired

symfony noob here.

Im not sure what this autowiring error is about.

I am trying to check if a button is clicked (maybe there is a better way to do this)

Like so(see first if)

```
 if ($button->get('submit')) {
        $parameters = [];

        $clientId = $request->get('client_id');
        $clientSecret = $request->get('client_secret');
        $playlistId = $request->get('playlist_id');

        if ($clientId && $clientSecret && $playlistId) {
            $parameters['client_id'] = $playlistId;
            $parameters['client_secret'] = $clientSecret;
            $parameters['playlist_id'] = $playlistId;
        }
        Validator::validateArrayKeys($parameters);
    }
```

This is my whole class, am i referencing something wrong here ? 
Or is there another way to check if a form has been submitted (I dont have a database)

```
  /**
 * @Route("/", name="app_index")
 */
public function index(Request $request, SubmitButton $button)
{

    $this->getParameters($request, $button);

    return $this->render('home/index.html.twig', [
        'controller_name' => 'HomeController',
    ]);
}


public function getParameters(Request $request, SubmitButton $button)
{
    $submitButton = $button->get('submit');

    dd($submitButton);

    if ($button->get('submit')) {
        $parameters = [];

        $clientId = $request->get('client_id');
        $clientSecret = $request->get('client_secret');
        $playlistId = $request->get('playlist_id');

        if ($clientId && $clientSecret && $playlistId) {
            $parameters['client_id'] = $playlistId;
            $parameters['client_secret'] = $clientSecret;
            $parameters['playlist_id'] = $playlistId;
        }
        Validator::validateArrayKeys($parameters);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is here:

```php
public function index(Request $request, SubmitButton $button)
```

Symfony can not infer what `$button` is. If you have a corresponding form then you should instantiate that form, handle the request and then you can check if the button was clicked, roughly like this:

```
public function index(Request $request)
{
    $form = $this->createForm(MyFormType::class);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
        if ($form->get('submit')->isClicked()) {
            // ...
        } else {
            // ...
        }
    }

    return $this->render('my_template.html.twig', ['form' => $form->createView()]);
}
```

Understandably that is a bit much if all you want to do is check if a button was clicked and you don't want to build a whole form around this. For this you can just access the submitted data from the request without having to resort to any form class whatsover:

```php
public function index(Request $request)
{
    $isClicked = $request->request->get('submit');

    // ...
}
```

Instead of `$request->request` this can be `$request->query` if you submitted the value using GET-method, rather than post.

See also:

- [Forms](https://symfony.com/doc/current/forms.html)
- [Request](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_foundation.html#accessing-request-data)

Comment: Hey, thank you for the answer. Since i am using POST and not GET, ii tried doing it like this.  $submitButton = $request->get('submit'); variable is empty thought... can i only do it via GET ?

Comment: I noticed that i have a button instead of an input type submit .. that was the fix.